# Display similar html/php pages with different content

Tags: php, html, web-frameworks

I am going to build a big project with a lot of similar pages. The layout will be completely similar to the pages, but the content will vary. 
My question is if it is best/quickest to build one page and then fetch different content from the database with the `$_GET` method or just manually build a lot of pages with the different information.
What gives best speed?

Comment: use a template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net) or any another

Comment: why not just code it raw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best speed would be to "just manually build alot of pages with the different information", but you will find that it is a nightmare to maintain because if you need to make a change on the header portion of the page, you will need to change EVERY single file! Plus the speed increase would most likely be negligible.

It's better, in my opinion, to simply have a layout. The very simplest way to do this without any template engines or frameworks is something like this:

layout.php

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='my-header'>
  <!-- Header content goes here -->
</div>

<div id="my-content">
<?php
  if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    // Query DB for content
  }
  else {
    // Display default page content
    echo 'default page';
  }

?>
</div>

<div id='my-footer'>
  <!-- Footer content goes here -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but what about having different html/php pages with content from a structured database?